# level([X|_], X, 1). how to get the level of a given value on a tree?

Tags: prolog

I've been trying to write a predicate to get the level of a given value on tree:

```
level([X|_], X, 1).
level([_, G, D], X, N) :-
   level(G, X, N1), 
   level(D, X, N2), 
   max(N1, N2, N3), 
   N is 1 + N3.
```

But it return : `false`

why?

Comment: Your code assumes that item ```X``` is on the root node (first clause of the definition), or in both subtrees ```G``` **and** ```D``` (second clause), is that true? I think that it is possible that ```X``` is in only one of the subtrees. In that case, the conjunction ```level(G, X, N1), level(D, X, N2)``` will be false.

Answer (score 0):

You do not state what happens if there is no such an element in your tree structure. One solution could be to add a "not available" atom to your code and toggle the cases accordingly.

For SWI Prolog:

```
max(na,na,na).
max(na,X,Y) :- dif(X,na), Y is X+1.
max(X,na,Y) :- dif(X,na), Y is X+1.
max(X,Y,Z) :- dif(X,na), dif(Y,na), Z is 1+max(X,Y).

level([], _, na).
level([X|_], X, 1).
level([_, G, D], X, N) :-
   level(G, X, N1), 
   level(D, X, N2), 
   max(N1, N2, N).
```

Another way would be to use other functions instead of `max` or another attribute to your predicate to keep track of the current depth.